# computer can ping to router lan ip from outside

Tags: networking, ping

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve

I have a computer with this IP address
10.0.0.1 / 255.255.255.0

and a router in the same network

the wan IP is: 10.0.0.5 / 255.255.255.0
and the LAN IP is: 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0

the computer can ping the router WAN IP
that it's obvious, but how can it be that the computer can ping router LAN IP 192.168.1.1, that it's the internal IP of the router when I'm doing in the computer
this command:

`ip route 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1`

[diagram screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muSgB.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're asking why your route… works? Are you intentionally using an incorrect gateway IP address? Are you perhaps reaching *some other* 192.168.1.1?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be able to ping an address, once it's been told where to reach it?

Comment: 10.0.0.1 its the ip of the computer , i didnt do route to 10.0.0.5 wan of the router

Comment: and i can ping the router internal ip

Comment: show us a diagram. that would help immensely

Comment: Where do you see the router's LAN & WAN addresses?

Comment: @FrankThomas i'v upload a picture

Comment: @harrymc the router wan is in the same network as the computers ip

Comment: That's not possible. The router is the bridge between the WAN and the LAN. There is some misunderstanding here.

Comment: https://i.imgur.io/qXsClht_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Comment: Show us screenshots of where you're finding these IPs.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX6M1.png

Answer (score 1):

You told the computer to send packets bound for the `192.168.1.0` network to `10.0.0.1`, so it sends the packets to the router. So the outbound packet gets to its destination.

The router knows how to reach `10.0.0.1` because it's in the same WAN subnet. So the return packet gets to its destination.

You don't explain why you think this wouldn't work. The route fixes the problem -- getting the outbound `ping` to the correct destination.

Comment: but when im adding another ip to the computer , this ip: 192.168.1.5 , without doing route in the cmd , then im not getting respone from the router but i can see when im doing arp -a , the mac of the router

Comment: That computer is not on the 192.168.1.5 network so how are the return packets going to get to it unless you add a route on the router?

Comment: i'v found out the problm . some one plug another router with the ip 192.168.1.1 in the 10.0.0.0/24 netowork